# Ruby object references vs collection references

Tags: ruby

I was going through The Well Grounded Rubyist and got confused by the following example.

Suppose we have an array of strings:

```
    numbers = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

If I freeze this array, I can't do the following:

```
    numbers[2] = "four"
```

That statement is a Runtime error, but this:

```
    numbers[2].replace("four")
```

is not.

The book explains that in the first of the last two statements, we are trying to access the array. That's what I found confusing because I thought we are trying to access the third element of the array, which is a string object. And how is that different from the last statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's different because in the statement that works you are calling `String#replace`. As you might expect, a call to `Array#replace` *will* fail.

```
numbers.replace [1,2,3]
TypeError: can't modify frozen array
```

The object reference at any given array index might be arbitrarily complicated and it's not the job of the frozen array to keep those objects from changing ... it just wants to keep the array from changing. You can see this:

```
ree-1.8.7> numbers[2].object_id
 => 2149301040 
ree-1.8.7> numbers[2].replace "four"
 => "four" 
ree-1.8.7> numbers[2].object_id
 => 2149301040
```

`numbers[2]` has the same `object_id` after `String#replace` runs; the Array did not actually change.

Comment: Ok, so the array did not change, but its elements did right? It now has ["one", "two", "four"]. What I am getting from this is that you cannot alter elements by a direct assignment but you can change them via method calls that correspond to their type.

Comment: As @steenslag points out, the object_ids did not change, so for the array, everything is intact. The first assignment was trying to change the object_id, which resulted in an error.

Comment: It's dangerous to think of *"an array"* in Ruby as being a collection of values. It's just a collection of *references* to *objects*. If instead of an array you had some other class, and that class contained various internal object references, and one of those referenced objects changed but kept its object_id, would you say the top-level object had changed? How would it even know?  What about an array of arrays?  If one of the element arrays changed, how would the top level object even know?

Comment: That's what I said. There was no change in Object-ids so the array is intact.

Comment: Si, I could tell that you had it figured out. But you asked a good question at the top and so I answered it for all the people that will come here later.

Comment: yep, much appreciated. There is so much to learn about Ruby, especially if you come from different languages. (C and some Java)

Answer (score 0):

An array is a list of object_id's. String#replace is special - it changes the string but it keeps the object_id. So the list of object_id's does not change and the Array does not detect any change.

You can freeze every string of the array. String#replace would then result in an error.